# How do I change a command PATH in macOS so I don't have to type out the entire PATH every time I want to run the command in terminal?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, path

I'm following along with a Microsoft Machine Learning tutorial, [here.](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/ml-dotnet/get-started-tutorial/install) I'd like to shorten the path so I don't have to run the command `~/.dotnet/tools/mlnet` in terminal (I'm on MacOS), especially since my current directory path is `~/myMLApp`, so now I have to back out of that directory and run the command like this `../.dotnet/tools/mlnet`.

Ideally, I'd just like to run the command `mlnet` wherever I am. I think I have to get to my bash profile and change the path, which I've done before but Google is so unhelpful with stuff like this because a lot of the search terms are reused and ambiguous. Also, I'm now using the new bash that was changed a bit ago with MacOS (it's called like z-shell or something?), so I don't know if the process is different.

Comment: This question appears to be more suitable for [apple.se] or [su], as it is not programming related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zsh` is in some ways backwards compatible with `bash`, which in some ways is backward compatible with the original `sh`.  As such, you can use the `~/.profile` or the `~/.bashrc`, or of course `~/.zshrc`.  In any of those files, add a line like:

```
export PATH=~/.dotnet/tools/:$PATH
```

and then you can just type `mlnet` in the Terminal.

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please press the check-mark icon to accept this as the answer.